# Handling App Uri generated from Deeplink by google adwords in Android app

Tags: android, google-ads-api, deep-linking

1. Handling Deeplinks in my Android App Format  {scheme}://{host_path}
   in my App.
2. Try to create Google Adwords Add. I converts the deeplink into App Uri .
   Format  android-app://{package_id}/{scheme}/{host_path}
3. The deeplink fails consequently.

[Deeplinks and App Uris](https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/6046977?hl=en)

4. What is the right way to handle this format of App Uri along with regular Deeplinks?